# Swift "Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to nil always returns true"

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to figure out why my thumbnails in my UICollectionView that are being downloaded from firebase jump all over the place meaning sometimes they will be in the correct cells and then sometimes they are duplicated and in the wrong places.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.postImage.image = nil
        if self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL != nil {
            cell.postImage.downloadImagezzz(from: self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL)
        } else {
            print("\n \(indexPath.row) could not return a value for pathToImage256 from Post. \n")
        }

        return cell
    }
```

I feel like the "!= nil" warning saying "Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to nil always returns true" is the problem. Need some help.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImagezzz(from imgURL: String) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, responds, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: That error means the value you are comparing to nil cannot be nil. I assume downloadURL is declared as `String` (and not `String?`).

Comment: Yes, I understand what it is saying. What I need help on is how to fix it. I am unsure how change it. Can you help please?

Comment: You may need to add more context to what your problem is. The problem may be in how your data is being assigned, I would take a look at the value of downloadURL when it is being assigned and make sure that the value isn't being altered before the tableView handles it.

Comment: What about it do you want to change?

Comment: You will need to share more info. What type of object is postImage? Can you share the code for the downloadImagezzz function?

Comment: I just added the code for the "downloadImagezzz"

Comment: postImage is just the identifier for the cell UIImage view

Comment: I was seeing stuff about people adding a NSCache but the way they were doing it was out of date

Comment: You are downloading the image asynchronously, by the time it finishes the cell may have been reused elsewhere in your collection. This would explain images jumping around and appearing in the wrong place. You should either cancel the outstanding data task, or verify the cell is still correct before setting the image.

Comment: I am unsure how to do either of those, I am a noob at coding

Comment: You might be better off using a library that handles this for you. Here are a few:
https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage